# Validation of proper number value

Tags: javascript, regex

The regex `/^-?\d*(\.\d+)?$/` does the proper validation for both negative and positive integer as well as decimal values. But I want the regex to be extended a bit to address the following also :

1. The value can be 0 but should not be -0. Only if it a floating value like 0.1 than the negative value should be supported.
2. Any number should not start with leading zero other than integer 0 itself or decimal values starting with 0.1 as for example. But there should not be any value like 00 or 00.01.
3. Validation of empty value.

The idea is to make sure a single regex does the complete validation instead of doing multiple checks.

Comment: Am I right that you want to forbid negative integer values?

Comment: > The idea is to make sure a single regex does the complete validation instead of doing multiple checks.
It's bad idea. Several simple checks are clearer and more reliable than one huge regexp.

Comment: @alexeyten : The regex given by OGHaza is exactly what i was looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heavily influenced by ilmirons answer:

```
^(0|-?(0\.\d+|[1-9]\d*(\.\d+)?))$
```

[RegExr](http://regexr.com?38gje)

Answer (score 1):

I think this should work:

`/^(0|-?(0.\d+|[1-9]\d*(\.?(\d+))?))$/`

Comment: Fixed, did not notice you already answered. Thanks for the credit :)

Answer (score 0):

```
  function isNumber(n) {
    return !isNaN(parseFloat(n)) && isFinite(n);
  }
```